# I'm having DLL trouble with F# Interactive on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2012, z3, f#-interactive

I am running VS 2012 on a 64 bit machine but I have set the "F# 64-bit Interactive" option to False which means it should default to a 32-bit process.

I am calling a 32-bit DLL and my program compiles ok but I get the dreaded DLL incompatibility error when I try running the program:

> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B).

Any ideas?

I tried both the 64-bit and 32-bit options but I get the same error. Everything runs fine with the non-interactive F# i.e. compiling with `fsc`.

Comment: Can you show your script file?

Comment: yes, knowing which dll would be useful